# What does a Haskell comment starting with `{- |` generally mean?

Tags: haskell, haddock

I see Haskell multi-line comments that sometimes start with `{- |` instead of just `{-`.

Does leading with the pipe character inside the comment mean something by convention?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `|` at the start of a comment is [Haddock](http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/markup.html) syntax that begins a documentation annotation. An example from the Haddock documentation is:

```
-- |The 'square' function squares an integer.
square :: Int -> Int
square x = x * x
```

It also goes on to say

> The “-- |” syntax begins a documentation annotation, which applies to the following declaration in the source file. Note that the annotation is just a comment in Haskell — it will be ignored by the Haskell compiler.

Comment: Specifically, it is a comment about something that follows the comment, whereas `-- ^` describes something that precedes the comment.